# Am i using Kafka right?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have installed Kafka "**kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0**".

Started services of both *zookeper* and *Kafka-server*.

Then i created a java project (kafka lib included) on IntelliJ.

I also included an SQLite jar needed for the JDBC connect.

I initially thought of using confluent.kafka-connect, but since mine is a windows based machine CLIplatform doesn't work.

So i wrote a *stand alone java program to connect to my sqlite DB fetched data* and sent this as a message using a custom Kafka-Producer program creating a topic "connect-test".

I received the same data using a custom Kafka-Consumer program.
The purpose of this test, is to see if i can do the same with an existing windows based, enterprise application to stream data into a warehouse for Data Analytics platforms.
I understand that i have done it in stand-alone mode, but am i in the right direction?

**Can you please suggest if there is a better way for me to integrate my enterprise application (java based Custom API + oracle DB +another layer on top of Oracle DB) with Kafka?**

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: in addition to @robin-moffatt 's answer kafka is not platform bound apart from [this bug under windows](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194) you can write your implementation and/or use an existing [connector](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/)

Comment: Apache Nifi or Streamsets would also work.

Comment: Thank you @Paizo for the hint, i will look into that as well. This is helpful.

Comment: @cricket_007, I have not looked into them yet, i will deep dive. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka, and is the recommended way for doing integration with other systems including databases. [This article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc) explains the specific options you have for integrating with Oracle, and [this talk](https://videos.confluent.io/watch/4cVXUQ2jCLgJNmg4kjCRqo) shows it in action.

> since mine is a windows based machine CLIplatform doesn't work.

Kafka Connect should work on Windows. I'm not sure what you mean by `CLIplatform` since it's Java-based it should run on Windows, and if not there are Docker images you can use.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent and wrote the above articles linked to*

Comment: Hi @Robin, Your articles are an inspiration for looking into Confluent. The "Command line interface" of confluent package is i believe still not readily usable to start all services on windows.

Comment: To add on...  Nevertheless, I am able to work by manually start zookeper & kafka-server but i am still wondering how do i start the "schema-registry-start" service on windows.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129210/start-confluent-schema-registry-in-windows).  I think i found something here which is relevant.

Comment: @Shashank Schema Registry now has Windows scripts, according to github https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/tree/master/bin/windows

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007 for the reference, i will try this out and comment if i progress.